# Cleanest way to map user accounts to picklist dropdown?

Tags: picklist

In a restricted environment (no Apex or adjustments to user records allowed), I have the task of creating picklist that are (at least loosely) mapped to user accounts that at record user can choose from.

I could create a flow where, upon choosing from a pre-determined dropdown, the flow does a get records looking for that user record. This is open to the fault of only retrieving the wrong record if there are multiple user accounts for the same person.

Any way to have this more tightly coupled, but also in a way that would work between multiple orgs (can't map user IDs directly)?

Thanks

Comment: Surely the flow could thus retrieve multiple matching user records and ask the user to then refine their selection to choose just the one?

Comment: I was hoping to not involve a screen flow.

Comment: You're not really in a position to be picky about your solution here, given your stated restrictions.